# Are Constant variables also class variables?

Tags: variables, static, constants

Are Constant variables also class variables, since a constant variable is a static variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the language you are speaking of on how classes and constants/final variables are implemented.

For instance, in Java:

Generally, a final variable is whats considered a constant. This means it can have no other value than what it is initialized to. However, it is not necessarily static. If we don't specifically declare it to be static, then a new variable will be allocated for every new instance of the class. Obviously, this is wasteful since every class has a variable that has the exact same value.

So, in Java, it is good practice to label a final variable static. That way, all classes share the same variable rather than having a hundred redundant copies.